# Ejecutar funcion de consulta al recargar página y mostrar resultados por defecto

Tags: javascript, ajax

les consulto, si me pueden ayudar con esto.
En una pagina con formulario que muestra los resultados de la consulta.
Quisiera que al cargar la pagina ya aparezcan resultados de una busqueda que determino por defecto, en evez de aparecer sólo el formulario.
La función que ejecuta el formulario es la siguiente,ya establecí los valores por defecto, y al enviar el formulario muestra la consulta como la quiero.
Lo que necesito es que esta sea una función específica que se ejecute únicamente al actualizar la página.

```
 function finalize() {
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var boton = document.querySelector('[type=submit]');

      form.onsubmit = e => { //function(e){}
      boton.disabled = true;
      var formData = new FormData(form);

     formData.append("edad_1",'20');
     formData.append("edad_2",'0');
     formData.append("hijosNum",'0');


    e.preventDefault();

        var result = new XMLHttpRequest( );
        result.open( 'POST', 'consulta.php' );

    result.onload = function( ){
            boton.disabled = false;
    
     var msg = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
       parseR(msg);
       form.reset();
   }
   result.send(formData);
 }
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví, gracias, borré todo lo referente a las referencios a las etiquetas del formulario para el que está formulada la función original.

```
function finalizar() {
  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("edad_1", '20');
  formData.append("edad_2", 0);
  formData.append("hijosNum", 0);

  var result = new XMLHttpRequest();
  result.open('POST', 'consulta.php');

  result.onload = function() {
    var msg = JSON.parse(result.responseText);

    parseR(msg);
    form.reset();
  }
  result.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar una explicación, aunque sea mínima, de lo que has hecho para resolverlo?  Con tan solo el código no es suficiente. Sino esta respuesta es calificada como de baja calidad.  Y posteriormente, al cabo de 12 horas, puedes marcala como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y todos puedan aprender de ella, gracias.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hola, borré todo lo referente a las referencios a las etiquetas del formulario para el que está formulada la función original.